# Auth::check() fails on an ajax call (sometimes)

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-4

I have a **logged** user that access my JavaScript app.

During the initialization, the app send a couple of Ajax calls to gather some informations.

Sometimes, I would say about one time out of ten, one of the calls abort in one of my route filters.

What I observed about it :

- doesn't occurs every time
- not always the same route *(call)*
- there can be more than one fail at a same time
- a simple page refresh  re-trigger the calls, and
  as it's not a constant failure, everything goes back to normal...
  until the next glitch.

Here's the filter that is faulty:
*I know it's this one because I replaced the `403` with `418` and it transformed the "forbidden" glitch into a "teapot" glitch.*

```
Route::filter('auth-api', function() {
   if (!Auth::check()) { App::abort(403, "Auth-api filter denied"); } 
});
```

And here's the strange bug in action :
*All the `/api/[whatever]` goes though the same filters, in this case, the `/api/assurances` died while the others went good.*

[image]

Comment: What session driver are you using?

Comment: In order to provide more info - you'll probably need to log your session data on each route before and after the check - and keep smashing your routes until the error appears - then see what the logs show. It *might* be related to something like this: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5416

Comment: I'm using the eloquent driver, I will see into this investigation as soon as I get back to my dev Env. Also, the github issue seems to pin point my problem. I will keep them tuned with my inputs

Comment: the eloquent driver is the *auth* driver - not the *session* driver. Which *session* driver are you using? File, redis, memcache etc? Perhaps try changing the session driver to see if the problem occurs using a different driver.

Comment: I'm using the "native" driver. I'm not able to reproduce the bug with the "cookie" driver. Based on my understanding of the GitHub thread and this experience, I think it means that the file based session doesn't work well with Ajax applications. What do you think about using the "cookie" driver (or any other driver) ?

Comment: I use redis or memcahce for all my applications that use sessions. They are fast, reliable, and designed for this type of situation. Depending on your server - it is often no more configuration required - they "just work"

Comment: thanks a lot, I will be able to solve this problem then, if you want to formulate an answer, I would be glad to accept it, even if it's more a way to bypass than a solution. I think it's the only option we have atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your sessions are failing for some reason. It is possibly due to the `file` session driver, which can lead to race conditions when accessed multiple times in short succession.

The best option is to change the session driver and test if the problem persists with another session driver. I recommend trying with Redis or Memcache - as these are designed to be fast, quick, and reliable.